# Magento 1 - Add VAT NUMBER column in Manage Customers Grid

Tags: magento-1.8, vat, customer-grid, custom-column-grid

I want to add a column in Manage Customers Grid

> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Grid.php

with the VAT Number of customers.

Now i have `ID`, `Name`, `Email`, `Telephone`, `Country` etc.

I need to add the attribute in prepare collection and the column in prepare columns.

Help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following way:

**Add the following code in config.xml which is related to overwrite grid**

> app/code/local/SR/MagentoCommunity/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <SR_MagentoCommunity>
            <version>0.0.0.1</version>
        </SR_MagentoCommunity>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <sr_magentocommunity>
                <class>SR_MagentoCommunity_Model</class>
            </sr_magentocommunity>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <sr_magentocommunity>
                <class>SR_MagentoCommunity_Block</class>
            </sr_magentocommunity>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <customer_grid>SR_MagentoCommunity_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Grid</customer_grid>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

And

> app/code/local/SR/MagentoCommunity/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Grid.php

```
<?php

class SR_MagentoCommunity_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid
{
    /**
     * @param Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection $collection
     */
    public function setCollection($collection)
    {
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('taxvat');
        parent::setCollection($collection);
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        parent::_prepareColumns();

        $this->addColumnAfter('taxvat', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('VAT Number'),
            'index'     => 'taxvat'
        ), 'customer_since');

        $this->sortColumnsByOrder();
        return $this;
    }
}
```

> app/etc/modules/SR_MagentoCommunity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <SR_MagentoCommunity>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </SR_MagentoCommunity>
    </modules>
</config>
```

[image: Grid]
[image: Detail Page From where comes Vat]

Comment: it shows an empty field. it's not working :(

Comment: Not sure why, check screenshot

Comment: can you point the path of the right config.xml? i think i have a problem there.

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: not working, image here [link](https://i.imgur.com/5v28nmH.png)

Comment: You definitely made mistake when overwrite inside your module.

Comment: Create independent module, clear cache

Comment: I have added app/etc/modules/SR_MagentoCommunity.xml too. So create 3 file for this simple module

Comment: Tried this options, created the files in the correct paths, pasted the contents for every file but no success.

Comment: Did you clear cache?

Comment: yes, cleared all cache, nothing happends. i think i will abbandon this :( i`m also waiting for other options.